# Embed Grafana dashboard in Angular 6 application

Tags: angular, grafana

I'd like to embed a Grafana dashboard inside an iframe into an Angular 6 application. I've generated an API key from the Grafana control panel, and I use it in the iframe URL as below:

```
<iframe src="https://api_key:GENERATED_API_KEY=@SERVER_URL:3300/DASHBOARD_URL" style="width: 50%; height: 100%; border: none">
</iframe>
```

It works in Firefox, but when I try to run the application from Chrome, it displays the following error in the console:

> Subresource requests whose URLs contain embedded credentials (e.g.
>   `https://user:pass@host/`) are blocked

Is there any workaround for this problem?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Please check below link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53605978/get-iframe-img-in-angular-6