# Get IFrame img in angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an iframe in my Angular app. The iframe has an image in base64 format. Now I am trying to get that image’s base64 code and store it in a variable in the parent page/Angular app. Can anyone assist, please? I found this article

[How to get data from Iframe with Angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52170003/how-to-get-data-from-iframe-with-angular-6)

Here is my HTML code for the iframe

```
<iframe src="http://eohdigitalappstore.co.za/test/test.html"></iframe>
```

I managed to get a bit further by being able to get elements in the iframe page but am now trying to get to the image in the elements tree

```
const doc =  this.iframe.nativeElement.contentDocument || this.iframe.nativeElement.contentWindow;
console.log(doc.body);
```

I can get to point in the HTML elements tree which looks like below
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a view child, it will give you `ElementRef` from which you can access a `nativeElement` object exactly same as you have it in a normal JavaScript application.

**Example** ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38457886/2988776)):

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('iframe') iframe: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const nativeEl =  this.iframe.nativeElement;
    if ( (nativeEl.contentDocument || nativeEl.contentWindow.document).readyState === 'complete' )        {
        nativeEl.onload = this.onIframeLoad.bind(this);
    } else {
      if (nativeEl.addEventListener) {
        nativeEl.addEventListener('load', this.onIframeLoad.bind(this), true);
      } else if (nativeEl.attachEvent) {
        nativeEl.attachEvent('onload', this.onIframeLoad.bind(this));
      }
    }
  }


  onIframeLoad() {
    const base64String = this.iframe.nativeElement.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
    console.log(this.iframe.nativeElement.contentWindow.document.body.children[1].currentSrc);
  }
}
```

Additional interesting readings: https://aakashgoel.com/capturing-the-load-event-of-an-iframe-a-case-study-1a3761c871fe

Note: All this is possible if you observe the [same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184676/discussion-between-ravinder-payal-and-skydev).